# Drawing a line chart in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to draw a line chart in Swift UI but can't implement the for loop:

```
Path { path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20))
    ForEach(0 ..< 11) { index in
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((index * 20) + 40), y: Int(hr[index])))
}
```

Gives me a build error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can
> conform to protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of solution:

```
Path { path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20))
    for index in 0 ..< 11 {
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ((index * 20) + 40), y: y_pos[index]))
    }
}
// .stroke(Color.red) // for demo stroked if inside ViewBuilder
```